# Creating jar artifact with JFX11 results in un-self-executing jar

Tags: java, artifact, javafx-11

I understand that people need Java installed on their system to run the jar. But if it's a JavaFX 11 (from gluonhq) project, I create the artifact and I can't double click it like I used to be able to with Java 1.8 (since JavaFX was included).

This is a huge pain because now I have to use .bat file containing:

```
java --module-path PATH_TO\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml -jar myjar.jar
```

**AND** notice the end-user has to have the jfx11 libraries somewhere on their disk!

How are you pros doing it? Surely, the user doesn't have to install JFX11 separately in order to run your JavaFX apps right?

Comment: Fx support was removed from Java. While I don't know your setup and for that can' say for sure: that seems like a very probable reason.

Comment: see also: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular and note especially the last section about a fat jar.